# tbl_summary: How to set t.test column to 2 decimal places (gtsummary)

Tags: r, summary, gtsummary

I'm pretty new to tbl_summary and am trying to set the t.test column to 2 decimal places.

I've tried several different things in the tbl_summary() line but it doesnt seem to change the t.test column. Tried adding in `style_fun = everything() ~ purrr::partial(style_number, digits = 2)` but that led to the following error message:  ... `must be empty. ✖ Problematic argument: • style_fun = everything() ~ purrr::partial(style_number, digits = 2)`.  Any ideas on how to change it?

Also, is it possible to change the CI column so that it reads as conf.low - conf.high instead of conf.low, conf.high.
Thank you!

I've used a mtcars example here to make it easier.

```
car <- mtcars[,c("am", "mpg", "qsec", "disp")]

car %>%
  dplyr::select(am, mpg, qsec, disp) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by="am",
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} (±{sd})"),
    digits = all_continuous() ~ 2
  ) %>%
  add_p(test = all_continuous() ~ "t.test") %>%
  modify_header(statistic ~ "**Test Statistic**") %>%
  modify_fmt_fun(statistic ~ style_number) %>%
  add_ci()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were right about using `modify_fmt_fun`, but `style_number` needs to be wrapped in a function.

```
library(gtsummary)

car <- mtcars[,c("am", "mpg", "qsec", "disp")]

car %>%
  dplyr::select(am, mpg, qsec, disp) %>%
  tbl_summary(
    by="am",
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} (±{sd})"),
    digits = all_continuous() ~ 2
  ) %>%
  add_p(test = all_continuous() ~ "t.test") %>%
  modify_header(statistic ~ "**Test Statistic**") %>%
  modify_fmt_fun(update = statistic ~ function(x) style_number(x, digits = 2)) %>%
  add_ci()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, @jrcalabrese, I encounter the similar issue, and the difference is that  I have the "statistic = list (all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ± ({sd})", all_categorical() ~ "{n} / {N} ({p}%)").  I tried the same code provided above, but I got error: Error:
! Error in `update=` argument input. Select from ‘variable’, ‘row_type’, ‘label’, ‘n’, ‘var_type’,
  ‘var_label’, ‘stat_0’, ‘ci_stat_0’ , could you please point me how to fix it? thx!

Comment: Hi @Rstudyer, I tried your code and I didn't get the error on my end. If you're not running the latest version, I would try updating R, RStudio, and gtsummary. If you still get the error, post this as a separate question and include what version of R, RStudio, and gtsummary you're running.